# Axios mock is undefined in unit test

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, axios, jestjs, mocking

Trying to mock my axios for a login page and am getting undefined when my submit method is being tested here:

```
submit() {
  var name = this.username.value.replace(/ /g, '%20')
  var url = 'http://localhost:8080/properties'

  console.log('PRINT THIS OUT')
  axios.get(
    url,  
    {      
    auth: 
    {
      username: name, 
      password: this.password.value
      
    }})
    .then((res) =>{
        console.log('inside AXIOS outside IF')
        console.log('this is the username ' + res.data)
      if(res.data.CurMember.name == this.username.value 
      && name !='' && this.password != '')
      {
        console.log('THIS IS INSIDE THE AXIOS IF')
        this.navigateToHome()
      }
      else
      {
        console.log('THIS IS INSIDE THE AXIOS ELSE')
        this.invalidLogin = true;
      }
    })
    .catch((error) =>{
      console.log('THIS IS INSIDE THE ERROR ')
      console.error(error)
    })
  },

navigateToHome() {
  console.log('THIS IS THE NAVIGATE')
  this.$router.push({name: "HomePage"});
},
```

Here is the test that calls this method:

```
import BasicLogin from '@/views/BasicLogin.vue'
import {shallowMount, mount, flushPromises} from "@vue/test-utils"
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import axios from 'axios'


jest.mock('axios', () => ({
            get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({mockDataCorrectLogin})),
    })) 


const mockData = 
[{
    'authType': 'string',
    'CurMember': {
        'name': 'bossman',
        'pass': 'bigboss!!',
        'role': 'string'
    },
    'version': "string"
}]


const mockDataCorrectLogin = 
{
    status: 200,
    data: mockData
}

describe('BasicLogin.vue', () => 
{
let wrapper = null

beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(BasicLogin, 
    {
        propsData:
        {
           //data go here
           usernameValue: '',
           passwordValue: '',
           
        },
    })
}),

it('Login as bossman, validate routing worked', async () => {
    
    //creates a mock router for the navigation to be used
    const mockRoute = {
        params: {
            id: 1
        }
    }
    const mockRouter = {
        push: jest.fn()
    }
    const wrapper = mount(BasicLogin, {
        global: {
            mocks: {
                $route: mockRoute, 
                $router: mockRouter
            }
        }
    })

    const inputFieldUser = wrapper.get('[type="text"]').element
    inputFieldUser.value = 'bossman'
    expect(inputFieldUser.value).toBe('bossman')

    const inputFieldPass = wrapper.get('[type="password"]').element
    inputFieldPass.value = 'bigboss!!'
    expect(inputFieldPass.value).toBe('bigboss!!')

    //await wrapper.get('button').trigger('click')
    await wrapper.vm.submit()
    //expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)

    //expect(mockRouter.push).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    //expect(mockRouter.push).toHaveBeenCalledWith({"name": "HomePage"})
})
})
```

From the error message, you can see that the axios.get error is being thrown,
instead of the app continuing to run and navigate the router.
This is because the axios mock data is undefined.
Here is the error:

```
 PASS  tests/unit/BasicLogin.spec.js
 ● Console

console.log src/views/BasicLogin.vue:73
  PRINT THIS OUT
console.log src/views/BasicLogin.vue:90
  inside AXIOS outside IF
console.log src/views/BasicLogin.vue:91
  this is the username undefined
console.log src/views/BasicLogin.vue:105
  THIS IS INSIDE THE ERROR 
console.error src/views/BasicLogin.vue:106
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'CurMember' of undefined
      at /home/bcduff2/jumpgate/web/src/views/BasicLogin.vue:92:23
```

So I am wondering why axios' data is undefined in the submit method? Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to answer my own question and am posting here for anyone else who may have the same issue:

I had to take the mock data and put it directly into the axios mock here

```
jest.mock('axios', () => ({
    get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({status: 200, data: {authType: 'string',
    CurMember: {
        name: 'bossman',
        pass: 'bigboss!!',
        role: 'string'
    },
    version: "string"}}))
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that `res.data` is `undefined` in:

```js
axios.get(/*...*/)
  .then((res) => {
    if(res.data.CurMember.name == this.username.value
       ^^^^^^^^
```

...which points to a problem with your mock:

```js
jest.mock('axios', () => ({
  get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({mockDataCorrectLogin})),
}))                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

...which does not contain a property named `data`, leading to the `undefined` error you observed.

It looks like `mockDataCorrectLogin` has the mock response (including the `data` property) you want to be returned, so the solution is to resolve that object itself:

```js
jest.mock('axios', () => ({
  get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(mockDataCorrectLogin)),
}))
```

Also, `mockData` is an array, but your code does not expect an array. That data should just be a single object:

```js
/*
const mockData = 
[{
    'authType': 'string',
    'CurMember': {
        'name': 'bossman',
        'pass': 'bigboss!!',
        'role': 'string'
    },
    'version': "string"
}]
*/

const mockData = 
{
    'authType': 'string',
    'CurMember': {
        'name': 'bossman',
        'pass': 'bigboss!!',
        'role': 'string'
    },
    'version': "string"
}
```

Comment: Tony, thanks for the reply. I followed what you said and now it appears to be getting into the data, however I am seeing the error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined at the same location. Would you be able to tell why this is also finding it to be undefined?

Comment: I see the issue. `mockData` is an array, but your code does not expect an array. Make `mockData` a single object. See updated answer.